# Display product attributes on specific Woocommerce product category archives page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I want to show two attributes on the category pages, with the attribute name and value only on specific categories.

This code that I found displays the labels of the attributes, but is duplicating the value and I am really struggling with a show if categories variable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','add_attribute');
function add_attribute() {
    global $product;

    $product_attributes = array( 'pa_set', 'pa_team');
    $attr_output = array();

    // Loop through the array of product attributes
    foreach( $product_attributes as $taxonomy ){
        if( taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ){
            $label_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
            $value = $product->get_attribute('pa_set');

               if( ! empty($value) ){
                // Storing attributes for output
                $attr_output[] = '<span class="'.$taxonomy.'">'.$label_name.': 
    '.$value.'</span>';
            }
        }
    }

    // Output attribute name / value pairs separate by a "<br>"
    echo '<div class="product-attributes">'.implode( '<br>', $attr_output 
    ).'</div>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** - The problem comes from the following line, where the product attribute attribute value is always for the same product attribute:

```
$value = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_set' );
```

and it should be this instead:

```
$value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );
```

The complete revisited code will be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','display_loop_product_attribute' );
function display_loop_product_attribute() {
    global $product;

    $product_attributes = array('pa_set', 'pa_team'); // Defined product attribute taxonomies.
    $attr_output = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through the array of product attributes
    foreach( $product_attributes as $taxonomy ){
        if( taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ){
            if( $value = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) ){
            // The product attribute label name
            $label_name = wc_attribute_label($taxonomy);
                // Storing attributes for output
                $attr_output[] = '<span class="'.$taxonomy.'">'.$label_name.': '.$value.'</span>';
            }
        }
    }
    // Output attribute name / value pairs separate by a "<br>"
    echo '<div class="product-attributes">'.implode('<br>', $attr_output).'</div>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**Targeting Product category archive pages:**

You will use [the conditional tag `is_product_category()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5) inside the function on an `IF` statement…

For specific product category archive pages, you can set them [as explained here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5) inside the function in an array, like:

```
if( is_product_category( array('chairs', 'beds') ) {
    // Here go the code to be displayed
}
```

You will just need to set the right product categories slugs in the array…

---

Related: [Show WooCommerce product attributes in custom home and product category archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129529/show-woocommerce-product-attributes-in-custom-home-and-product-category-archives/55131199#55131199)

Comment: Thank you LoicTheAztec! The code worked great but where ever I place the  if statement it bombs out on me. Where exactly do I need to place it?