# Show WooCommerce product attributes in custom home and product category archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

The below code that displays product attributes on product category archive pages and is based on *"[Display product attributes on specific Woocommerce product category archives page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510707/display-product-attributes-on-specific-woocommerce-product-category-archives-pag/53510826#53510826)"* answer thread.

However, when I add that category on the homepage, It does not display the attributes.

My code version:

```
// Show Attributes on Product Category Page 
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','display_loop_product_attribute' );
function display_loop_product_attribute() {
    global $product;

    //$product_attributes = array('pa_size', 'pa_color');
    $product_attributes = array('pa_size');
    $attr_output = array();

    // Loop through the array of product attributes
    foreach( $product_attributes as $taxonomy ){
        if( taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ){
            if( $value = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) ){
                // The product attribute label name
                $label_name = get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name;
                // Storing attributes for output
                $attr_output[] = '<span class="'.$taxonomy.'">'.$label_name.': '.$value.'</span>';
            }
        }
    }
    // Output attribute name / value pairs separate by a "<br>"
    echo '<div class="product-attributes-custom">'.implode('<br>', $attr_output).'</div>';
}
```

I can't figure out how to make it work on my custom homepage that display products and on specific product category pages. For the homepage I know that the conditional tag to be used is **`is_home()`**… But how can I make it work for product category pages too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated - The following code will display specific product attributes on:

- **Home page** for a custom products loop using [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/) WordPress conditional tag
- Defined **product category archive pages** using [`is_product_category()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5) Woocommerce conditional tag

The code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','display_loop_product_attribute' );
function display_loop_product_attribute() {
    global $product;

    // The Product attribute to be displayed
    $product_attributes = array('pa_size');

    // The targeted Product category archive pages (slugs)
    $categories = array('t-shirts', 'hoodies', 'socks');

    $output = array(); // Initializing

    // Targetting home page and specific product category archive pages
    if( is_front_page() || is_product_category($categories) ) {

        // Loop through the array of product attributes
        foreach( $product_attributes as $taxonomy ){
            if( taxonomy_exists($taxonomy) ){
                if( $values = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) ){
                    // The product attribute label name
                    $label_name = get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name;

                    // Storing attributes for output
                    $output[] = '<span class="'.$taxonomy.'">'.$label_name.': '.$values.'</span>';
                }
            }
        }

        // Output attribute name / value pairs, separate by a "<br>"
        echo '<div class="product-attributes-custom">'.implode('<br>', $output).'</div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Addition:** To format each attribute term name in it's own `<span>` tag…

**Insert** in the function code, **after** this line:

```
                    // The product attribute label name
                    $label_name = get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name;
```

The following:

```
                    // convert string of term names to an array
                    $values = explode(', ', $values);
                    // Format each and set back to a string
                    $values = '<span>' . implode('</span> <span>', $values) . '</span>';
```

---

Related: [Display product attributes on specific Woocommerce product category archives page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510707/display-product-attributes-on-specific-woocommerce-product-category-archives-pag/53510826#53510826)

Comment: Thank @LoicTheAztec for your solution, It worked like a charm! the only issue was you forgot to put ' in your array initiation which was very easy to spot.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztech , I have accepted your answer. One more thing I was wondering that is there any chance we can style the attributes ? right now they all are showing up in Single <span> element like this <span class="pa_size">Size: Euro 41 / 10.5 - 11 US, Euro 42 / US 11.5 - 12</span> How can I add each size in different span so that It becomes easy to style them ?

Comment: @Jacob I have lightly updated the code (variable renamed) and added an addition for you (to be insert inserted the function code) that will do what you are asking.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank for the code Loic. It works perfect but the attribute names are appearing below "add to cart button" at woocommerce product loop. How can I make the attributes appear above "add to cart button" ?